# SQL Group By with Inner Joins

Tags: sql

MS Access has generated the following query:

```
SELECT Port.portName, Auth.portID, 
    Region.RegionName, Region.RegionID, 
    Auth.authID
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN (Auth INNER JOIN Port ON Auth.portID = Port.portID) 
    ON Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID;
```

and I want to

```
GROUP BY Region.RegionID
```

When I add it to the end it tells me that PortName is not part of an aggregate function. Could someplete plase advise how to do this? I've tried inserting it at various points in the SQL but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why you want to add `GROUP BY Region.RegionID`? since you are not doing any aggregation.

Comment: The whole idea of grouping by something means you're aggregating something else. Ex. total dollars per department, you would group by department, and sum by dollars. Grouping by department without summing by dollars does not make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As you may have noticed, I'm not great with SQL. Basically when I run the query there will be multiple entries with the same Region ID, I want to change this so that it will only ever list the same unique ID once.

Comment: don't you need to have either have the selected attributes contained in aggregate functions or the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: If you want one row per region, how do you want to treat the fact that there are multiple ports at each region? Do you want the first (min), the last (max), all of them in an aggregated list (I don't believe access has a function but normally you would use group_concat, listagg, string_agg, etc.) There are multiple ports at each region, so you have to aggregate those ports, in one way or another, to have one row per region.

Comment: Brian you explination makes sence and was the advice I was looking for. I'll look to restrucutre things around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects the port with the greatest id per region

```
SELECT 
    Port.portName, 
    Auth.portID, 
    Region.RegionName, 
    Region.RegionID, 
    Auth.authID
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN Port ON Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID
INNER JOIN Auth ON Auth.portID = Port.portID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(Port.portID) max_portID, Port.RegionID
    FROM Port
    GROUP BY Port.RegionID
) t1 ON t1.RegionID = Port.RegionID AND t1.max_portID = Port.portID
```

The above query assumes there is only 1 `Auth` per `Port` but if there can be multiple `Auth` per `Port` you'll need to similarly select only the max `Auth` to avoid duplicate Regions in the result.

```
SELECT 
    Port.portName, 
    Auth.portID, 
    Region.RegionName, 
    Region.RegionID, 
    Auth.authID
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN Port ON Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID
INNER JOIN Auth ON Auth.portID = Port.portID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(Port.portID) max_portID, Port.RegionID
    FROM Port
    GROUP BY Port.RegionID
) t1 ON t1.RegionID = Port.RegionID AND t1.max_portID = Port.portID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(Auth.authID) max_authID, Auth.portID
    FROM Auth
    GROUP BY Auth.portID
) t2 ON t2.portID = Port.portID AND t2.max_authID = Auth.authID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to do this?:

```
SELECT Region.RegionID, Region.RegionName, Port.portName, Auth.authID
FROM Auth
INNER JOIN Port ON Port.portID = Auth.portID 
INNER JOIN Region ON Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID
ORDER BY Region.RegionID
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I believe you mean to use a `DISTINCT` keyword rather than `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Port.portName, 
Auth.portID, 
Region.RegionName, 
Region.RegionID, 
Auth.authID
FROM Region 
INNER JOIN Port ON Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID
INNER JOIN Auth ON Auth.portID = Port.portID);
```

Comment: It's not duplicating rather giving a correct result. since you have a relation like `Region.RegionID = Port.RegionID`; it could be the case that `Region.RegionID 1` is related to multiple ports `Port.RegionID 1 2 3` and in such case joining them will fetch multiple records where `Region.RegionID` will be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT Port.portName, Auth.portID, Region.RegionName, Region.RegionID, Auth.authID
FROM Region INNER JOIN Auth on Region.RegionID=Auth.portID inner join Port on
Port.portID=Auth.portID group by Port.portName, Auth.portID, Region.RegionName, Region.RegionID, Auth.authID;